# cURL - Write to file

Tags: xml, file, curl

I have a problem with writing to a file with cURL.

I am targeting a ticket system and create a ticket with cUrl. This works completely fine. The response is the following

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100   136  100    51  100    85    246    410 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   414
{"id": 132234998736, "result": 232, "error": null}
```

In the end I need the last line in an XML file I called with a temporary name (for example 13381981.xml)

Now when I am using the

```
-O "13381981.xml"
```

in my code the file can't be found with an additional message curl: Remote file name has no length!.

What am I missing that I can write into an XML file?

So here is a full example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"params":["Header","Tickettext"], "method":"ticket.create", "id" 132234998131}' -o "test.xml" -u trac:trac http://test:8080/login/jsonrpc
```

Comment: Now I won't get an error message, but no answer from the ticket system

Comment: If I am not using the -o with the filename everything works...does it need to be in a special position in the request?

Comment: okay, fixed it a lil bit, still says it won't find the file :S

Comment: added the whole command

Comment: It works with double quotes, too. Just can't find the file and it seems it does not get created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you pass to `--data` needs to be quoted properly as right now it contains spaces and will thus be counted as multiple arguments. curl will then treat arguments that don't start with dash (-) as a URL and things will go downwards from there.

One possibility is to enclose the entire thing within single quotes (which won't work on Windows though):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"params":["Header","Tickettext"], "method":"ticket.create", "id" 132234998131}' -o "test.xml" -u trac:trac http://test:8080/login/jsonrpc
```

Comment: Ah, I missed those while retyping the code, I used them before and still use them :S

As I mentioned, the request to the server works and I get the answer I need....I'm just not getting it written into a file because I really only need the number from the result in line {"id": 132234998736, "result": 232, "error": null}

Comment: Sorry can't parse that. The command line works and saves the response in a file. It answers what you asked about. Now you seem to be changing the question...

Comment: Yeah, it seems wierd....also no error is presented when starting this, but if I try to open the file it can't find the file....that's really wierd...

Comment: There must be a problem in the system, but thanks anyways for the -O mistake I did first, now it works at least, though no file is there yet :D